# winui 3 C++ accessing the UI objects from background thread

Tags: c++, windows, winui-3

I'm new to windows desktop programming, winui 3, and just getting back to C++ after having not programmed it for several years. I am working in Visual Studio and much of this is generated code.

I have a desktop app that doesn't display a main window but it needs to display a dialog periodically to get confirmation from the user. I have defined the content dialog inside MainWindow.xaml.

```
<Window
    x:Class="Consent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Consent"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ContentDialog x:Name="consentDialog" Title="Dummy Title" CloseButtonText="Dummy Close">
            Dummy Content
        </ContentDialog>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The ContentDialog object is declared in MainWindow.xaml.g.h like this:

```
    ::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog _consentDialog{nullptr};

    ::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ContentDialog consentDialog()
    {
        return _consentDialog;
    }
```

In App::OnLaunched, I do

window = make<MainWindow>();

but don't activate the window.

Later as the app is running under a background thread, I need to be able to display the ContentDialog. If I was displaying the dialog from a button click, then the button click handler would be defined in MainWindow.xaml.cpp and I would have access to all the UI objects. But I don't know how to get a reference to the ContentDialog to use in the background thread.

I thought I could get it from the window object after the make function but that object is not of type MainWindow. If I could get the MainWindow object from window and then save it somewhere that would probably work.

My other thought is if there is an event I can define in MainWindow.xaml.cpp that will get called upon window creation, then maybe I can save a reference to the ContentDialog. Or maybe there is some other way to directly expose the ContentDialog control from within MainWindow.xaml.g.h.

Comment: What you do is far from being super clear, describing code in english is not the most efficient. You should post a simple project reproducing the issue somewhere [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For Contentdialog on application startup, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78180332/contentdialog-on-startup.

Answer (score 0):

The `MainWindow` type can be assigned, for example

```
winrt::App2Cpp::MainWindow window1 = make<MainWindow>();
window1.Activate();
```

But only things defined in `MainWindow.idl` can be accessed. You need to define your methods in the IDL file. See [Introduction to Microsoft Interface Definition Language 3.0#Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro#methods), [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property) and [XAML items controls; bind to a C++/WinRT collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection) for more information.

Then you can access your defined things in other threads. You may have a look at [Threading functionality migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/threading#change-windowsuicorecoredispatcher-to-microsoftuidispatchingdispatcherqueue) and [DispatcherQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/dispatcherqueue).

Comment: I wrote up an extended answer but when I clicked to format some xaml content I lost my entire post. Unfortunately this is the abbreviated version. I couldn't figure out what you were asking after reading through that stuff. I ended up saving references to the UI objects in the loaded event handler of the root UI element and then referencing them in the background thread.